# SSRS Column Visibility for selected IDs

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have a report with the column "Order-C Amount". But only a few selected employees are allowed to see this column. When the employees open the report, they always can only see their own data.

How do I set the expression on the column visibility?

I tried something like `=NOT(Field!ID.value = "12345") OR NOT(Field!ID.value ="123456")`.

With only one condition it works just fine. With more than one, the column just stays invisible for everyone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=NOT(Field!ID.value = "12345" OR Field!ID.value ="123456")
```

Comment: No worries, I've had the same problem with `NOT` before.